# Disable / enable input field

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to enable a disabled `INPUT`. I tried combinations with:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')",inputLname);
```

`inputLname` is my webelement but it didn't work I get NullPointerException

input "Last name": http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2013/09/test.html

Comment: Which line causes Null Pointer Exception?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium was created to interact with websites as a user would. In this case the user can't interact with the Last name field because it is disabled. Since this is a test site, it's not really a good, real world scenario. In a real world scenario, there would be a way to enable the `INPUT` field so you would code what the user would do to enable the `INPUT`. In this case, the user can't interact with the page in such a way to enable the `INPUT`. But... since this is an educational exercise, here's how I would do this.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('lname')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');");
```